# E-form content blocked by browser

Tags: browser, coldfusion, ssl-certificate

I have been given a task to fix a problem on a website. The website was created using ColdFusion and there's also eform included in some of the pages. The problem is whenever I'm trying to view the page with an eform in it, it will be blocked by the browser (only the eform is blocked, others can be view normally). Only IE version 7 or 8 will be able to view it.

If being viewed in latest IE (Chrome and Firefox also cannot view the eform). It will display this message :-

```
  Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate. 


  For more information, see “About Certificate Errors” in Internet Explorer Help.
```

I thought the problem is with the Untrusted Site Certificate or Self-Sign Certificate,so I google and try some of the solutions but failed. The odd thing is other content can be view except the eform.

Here is one of page code with an eform if some of you are wondering about the code;-

```
<cfinclude template="#request.siteContext.appSettings.header#">
<cfinclude template="_LANGnext_form2.cfm" />
<cfheader name="P3P" value='CP="CAO PSA OUR"'>
<cfoutput>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="#REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.root#/search/css/common.css">
</cfoutput>
<!---<cfparam name="url.idappli" default="0" />--->
<cfparam name="form.select" default="0" />
<cfparam name="url.userid" default="0" />
<cfparam name="form.idappli" default="0" />

<cfscript>
    CreateObject("component","ipo.util.title").header("#HdrProfile#,#HdrProfile2#,#HdrProfile3#, #HdrProfile4#");
</cfscript> 

<cfquery name="qRead" datasource="#REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.dsn2#" >
    SELECT  EXTIDAPPLI, IDAPPLI, IDAGENT, IDPERSON, DTAPPLI, LGSTAPPLI, DTPUBAPPLI,TYAPPLIC
    FROM    SOPRANO.PTAPPLI
    WHERE   EXTIDAPPLI like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#FORM.idappli#" />
</cfquery>



<cfif #form.idappli# NEQ '0'>

<cfif isdefined('qRead.recordcount') NEQ 0 AND #qRead.recordcount# NEQ '0'>

    <cfif IsDate(qRead.DTAPPLI)>
        <cfset dtapplication = CreateODBCDate(qRead.DTAPPLI) />
    <cfelse>
        <cfset dtapplication = "" />
    </cfif>

    <cfset dtNow         = CreateODBCDate(NOW()) />

    <cfquery name="qSts" datasource="#REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.dsn2#" >
        SELECT  DESCSTATUS
        FROM    SOPRANO.STATUS
        WHERE   IDSTATUS = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#qRead.LGSTAPPLI#" />
    </cfquery>

    <cfset LOCAL.currentStatus = qRead.LGSTAPPLI />
    <cfset LOCAL.currentStatusdesc = qSts.DESCSTATUS />

    <cfquery name="qLgsts" datasource="#REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.dsn#" >
        SELECT  CD_FRM
        FROM    CLEGALSTS
        WHERE   CD_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#LOCAL.currentStatus#" />
        AND     CD_TYPE = 'TM'
    </cfquery>

<!---       <CFSET  idappli = '#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#'> --->        

    <CFOUTPUT>          
        <cfform name="myForm" method="post" action="new_pt.cfm">
            <fieldset style="border:2px solid maroon">
                <legend style="font-weight:bold"><cfoutput>#SubTitle#</cfoutput></legend>
                <table class="MainContent" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"  align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <cfif form.select eq '01'>                  
                                <!--- <cfset url1 = 'http://172.16.0.56:8080/lfserver/Form1?userid=#userid#'> --->
                                <cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form1?userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username) />
                                <iframe id="efrm" src="template/tmp_url.cfm?url1=<cfoutput>#url1#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
                                <!--- <iframe id="efrm" src="<cfoutput>#URLDecode(url1)#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe> --->
                            <cfelseif form.select eq '14'>
                                <cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form14?userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username)>
                                <iframe id="efrm" src="template/tmp_url.cfm?url1=<cfoutput>#url1#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
                            <cfelseif form.select eq '2A'>
                                <cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form2A?userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username)>
                                <iframe id="efrm" src="template/tmp_url.cfm?url1=<cfoutput>#url1#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
                            <cfelseif form.select eq '5C'>
                                <cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form5C?appno=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#&userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username)>

                                <cfif ListFind(qLgsts.CD_FRM,"5C",",") EQ 0>
                                    <cfset proceed = false />

                                    <cfmodule template="#request.siteContext.appSettings.root#/include/tabletop.cfm" width="50%">
                                        <div align="center"><p>
                                        Cannot proceed with Patent Form 5C.<br />
                                        Current Application Status = "#LOCAL.currentStatusdesc#"
                                        </p></div>
                                    <cfmodule template="#request.siteContext.appSettings.root#/include/tablebottom.cfm">
                                <cfelse>
                                    <cfset proceed = true />
                                </cfif> 

                                <cfif proceed>
                                    <iframe id="efrm" src="template/tmp_url.cfm?url1=<cfoutput>#url1#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
                                </cfif>
                            <cfelseif form.select eq '5F'>  
                                <cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form5F?appno=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#&userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username)>

                                <cfif ListFind(qLgsts.CD_FRM,"5F",",") EQ 0>
                                    <cfset proceed = false />

                                    <cfmodule template="#request.siteContext.appSettings.root#/include/tabletop.cfm" width="50%">
                                        <div align="center"><p>
                                        Cannot proceed with Patent Form 5F.<br />
                                        Current Application Status = "#LOCAL.currentStatusdesc#"
                                        </p></div>
                                    <cfmodule template="#request.siteContext.appSettings.root#/include/tablebottom.cfm">
                                <cfelse>
                                    <cfset proceed = true />
                                </cfif> 

                                <cfif proceed>
                                    <iframe id="efrm" src="template/tmp_url.cfm?url1=<cfoutput>#url1#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
                                </cfif>
                            <cfelseif form.select eq '5H'>
                                <cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form5H?appno=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#&userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username)>
                                <iframe id="efrm" src="template/tmp_url.cfm?url1=<cfoutput>#url1#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
                            <cfelseif form.select eq '5I'>
                                <cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form5I?appno=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#&userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username)>
                                <iframe id="efrm" src="template/tmp_url.cfm?url1=<cfoutput>#url1#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
                            <cfelseif form.select eq '11'>
                                <cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form11?appno=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#&userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username)>

                                <cfif ListFind(qLgsts.CD_FRM,"11",",") EQ 0>
                                    <cfset proceed = false />

                                    <cfmodule template="#request.siteContext.appSettings.root#/include/tabletop.cfm" width="50%">
                                        <div align="center"><p>
                                        Cannot proceed with Patent Form 11.<br />
                                        Current Application Status = "#LOCAL.currentStatusdesc#"
                                        </p></div>
                                    <cfmodule template="#request.siteContext.appSettings.root#/include/tablebottom.cfm">
                                <cfelse>
                                    <cfset proceed = true />
                                </cfif> 

                                <cfif proceed>
                                    <iframe id="efrm" src="template/tmp_url.cfm?url1=<cfoutput>#url1#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
                                </cfif>
                            <cfelseif form.select eq '12'>
                                <cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form12?appno=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#&userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username)>

                                <cfif ListFind(qLgsts.CD_FRM,"12",",") EQ 0>
                                    <cfset proceed = false />

                                    <cfmodule template="#request.siteContext.appSettings.root#/include/tabletop.cfm" width="50%">
                                        <div align="center"><p>
                                        Cannot proceed with Patent Form 12.<br />
                                        Current Application Status = "#LOCAL.currentStatusdesc#"
                                        </p></div>
                                    <cfmodule template="#request.siteContext.appSettings.root#/include/tablebottom.cfm">
                                <cfelse>
                                    <cfset proceed = true />
                                </cfif> 

                                <cfif proceed>
                                    <iframe id="efrm" src="template/tmp_url.cfm?url1=<cfoutput>#url1#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
                                </cfif>
                            <cfelseif form.select eq '17'>
                                <cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form17?appno=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#&userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username)>
                                <iframe id="efrm" src="template/tmp_url.cfm?url1=<cfoutput>#url1#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
                                <!---fitri--->
                            <cfelseif form.select eq '22'>
                                <!--- <!---<cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form17?appno=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#&userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username)>--->
                                <iframe id="efrm" src="../fitri/form22.cfm" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
                                <!---end fitri---> --->
                                <cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form22?appno=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#&userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username)>
                                <iframe id="efrm" src="template/tmp_url.cfm?url1=<cfoutput>#url1#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
                            <cfelseif form.select eq 'renew'>
                                <cflocation url="renew.cfm?jenis=renew&idappli=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#" addtoken="no">
                            <cfelseif form.select eq 'surcharge'>
                                <cflocation url="renew.cfm?jenis=renew&idappli=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#" addtoken="no">
                                <!---<cflocation url="surcharge_payment.cfm?jenis=surcharge&extidappli=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#" addtoken="no">--->
                            <cfelseif form.select eq 'PM36(b)'>
                                <cflocation url="attachment.cfm?jenis=PM36(b)&idappli=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#" addtoken="no">
                            <cfelseif form.select eq 'PM36(a)'>
                                <cflocation url="attachment.cfm?jenis=PM36(a)&idappli=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#" addtoken="no">
                            <cfelseif form.select eq 'PM59(a)'>
                                <cflocation url="attachment.cfm?jenis=PM59(a)&idappli=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#" addtoken="no">
                            <cfelseif form.select eq 'PM59(b)'>
                                <cflocation url="attachment.cfm?jenis=PM59(b)&idappli=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#" addtoken="no">
                            <cfelseif form.select eq 'PM59(c)'>
                                <cflocation url="attachment.cfm?jenis=PM59(c)&idappli=#qRead.EXTIDAPPLI#" addtoken="no">



                            </cfif>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="center">     
                        <td class="parfont"><br>
                            <cfinput type="button" name="return" value="#BtnBack#" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='new_pt.cfm'" class="button2" style="width:80px">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </cfform>
    </CFOUTPUT> 

    <cfelseif isdefined('qRead.recordcount') NEQ 0 AND #qRead.recordcount# EQ 0>
        <cfform name="myForm">
            <table class="MainContent" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"  align="center">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>Application Number Not Found.<br /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td><cfinput type="button" name="return" value="#BtnBack#" onClick="javascript:self.history.back()" class="button2" style="width:80px"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>    
        </cfform>
    </cfif>
<cfelse>  
        <cfform name="myForm" method="post" action="new_pt.cfm">
        <table class="MainContent" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"  align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <cfif form.select eq '01'>                  
                            <cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form1?userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username) />
                            <iframe id="efrm" src="template/tmp_url.cfm?url1=<cfoutput>#url1#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
                        <cfelseif form.select eq '2A'>
                            <cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form2A?userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username)>
                            <iframe id="efrm" src="template/tmp_url.cfm?url1=<cfoutput>#url1#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>
                        <cfelseif form.select eq '14'>
                            <cfset url1 = URLEncodedFormat(REQUEST.siteContext.appSettings.eformserver& '/lfserver/Form14?userid='& SESSION.ipouser.username)>
                            <iframe id="efrm" src="template/tmp_url.cfm?url1=<cfoutput>#url1#</cfoutput>" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="800"></iframe>                       </cfif>
                    </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
     </cfform>

</cfif> 
<cfinclude template="#request.siteContext.appSettings.footer#">
```

Comment: The problem is still the certificate - it's the one from the eform server. It is likely (given that older versions CAN view it) that the cert has a bit strength that is too low, or enforces or allows an older handshake version of TLS. updating the cert and intermediate certs on the eform server (the URL filling all these iframes) will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I've been thinking about that also. Since I discovered that when I try to access the eform server directly, an error occur on the certificate.

Comment: Okay now I have a different problem. The eform have the same domain name with the main site. So how do I bind the same domain name with different port? Is it possible?

Comment: You use a colon as in https://www.example.com:8080

Comment: I'm using IIS to set the SSL binding. As I was saying, the main site and the eform server have the same domain name. I already set the https (port 443) for the main site. I tried adding another https (port 448) for the eform server but failed (both sites cannot be access). Did I do something wrong or it cannot be achieve?

Comment: This is a server config issue. What you want to do may be possible, but a cert is _DOMAIN_ specific in most cases. So maybe not.